# Laying out controls on ASP Web Form using markup

Tags: asp.net

![enter image description here][1]I am new to ASP.NET and I am trying to recreate an existing Winform calculator application in ASP.NET. It is basically a bunch of text boxes on two different tab pages.   I am having trouble laying out the text box controls on a web page.  I have the Telerik UI Controls Library available.  Should I be using a grid, tables ?

I have include a screen shot of the existing Winforms application.

Thanks for any help.

Sorry I am a new memeber so I can't post the image.  It consists of six groups of text boxes; 3 on the left side of the form and 3 on the right side.

Comment: I do not see the screenshot. But if you are new to web development, read up on CSS instead of using tables.

Comment: The easiest way to do it would be to create a table with three rows and two columns and put textboxes inside. You can also style it with css to give it the appearance you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto Table menu to insert a table. Please see image.[image: Table]

Then select textbox from toolbox(double click it or drap down to the cell).
[image: textbox]